# View feeds in Firefox not Google

Tags: firefox, rss, feed

Whenever I click on an RSS or Atom feed link in Firefox (3.5.2), I am redirected to:

```
http://www.Google.com/ig/add?feedurl=...
```

Which is a Google service that prompts me to add the feed to my feed reader account. Did I install some add-on that causes this? How do I get rid of it. I just want to see the feed in the way that IE or Chrome would render it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click Tools->options and navigate to Applications Tab

Change Web Feed to "Preview in Firefox". "Google" appears since you have chosen to "always choose google as your default feed reader"